# JSON is getting serialized with WriteAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions

I am calling an API with:

```cs
content =  await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var response = req.CreateResponse(request.StatusCode);
await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(content, request.StatusCode);

return response;
```

and it seems to be ok and working but the JSON is coming out like this:

```json
"{\"Policy_reference\":\"P12300025\"}"
```

Full code:

```cs
var data = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var request = await GetSubmissions.PostAsync("api", data);
                        
if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    content =  await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var response = req.CreateResponse(request.StatusCode);
    await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(content, request.StatusCode);
    
    return response;
}
```

### Update

This now working because I have implemented WriteStringAsync but I am receiving text in Postman:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[`WriteAsJsonAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponsejsonextensions.writeasjsonasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpresponsejsonextensions-writeasjsonasync(microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpresponse-system-object-system-type-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) is encoding the value you give it to a JSON, so you are essentially double-encoding the string. Instead you should use [`WriteAsync'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponsewritingextensions.writeasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpresponsewritingextensions-writeasync(microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpresponse-system-string-system-threading-cancellationtoken)):

```
content =  await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var response = req.CreateResponse(request.StatusCode);
await response.WriteAsync(content);

return response;
```

Comment: This is working perfectly but it is giving me text inside of Postman

Comment: You probably need to set the content type. Try `response.ContentType = "application/json";`

Comment: I get what your saying but i am recieving , contentType is not in httpresponsedata

Comment: its strange, i am doubling it up as you said and now when i just send it as WriteAsync its giving me the nice looking JSON but its content type is text - i think...

Comment: What do you mean by "text inside of Postman"?  JSON is nothing but a text string.  It only becomes a structure when some program decodes it.

Answer (score 2):

Your are trying to write a string as JSON, so you will encounter double serialization, just write it as string. Assuming you are using [`HttpResponseDataExtensions.WriteAsJsonAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httpresponsedataextensions.writeasjsonasync?view=azure-dotnet), then you can try [`HttpResponseDataExtensions.WriteStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httpresponsedataextensions.writestringasync?view=azure-dotnet):

```cs
await response.WriteStringAsync(content);
```

Or try `WriteAsync` from [`HttpResponseWritingExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponsewritingextensions.writeasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpresponsewritingextensions-writeasync(microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpresponse-system-string-system-threading-cancellationtoken)):

```
await response.WriteAsync(content);
```

Note that possibly you will need to set the content type by hand:

```cs
response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Are you sure that `WriteStringAsync` exists?

Comment: @DavidG I was referring to [`HttpResponseDataExtensions.WriteAsJson`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httpresponsedataextensions.writeasjsonasync?view=azure-dotnet). Do not have appropriate Azure functions set up at hand TBH.

Comment: So... no then! :)

Comment: @DavidG yep) Though `request.StatusCode` is passed to `WriteAsJsonAsync` and I see such overload in `HttpResponseDataExtensions` but not in `HttpResponseJsonExtensions`.

Comment: I'm not sure you got what I asked. You wrote `WriteAsString` in your answer, you came up with that method that doesn't exist.

Comment: @DavidG it does exist - check out the links, at least according to docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use this approach ...

```
return new ContentResult()
{
    Content = content,
    ContentType = "application/json",
    StatusCode = 200
};
```